# Ethernet stopped working after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

I recently upgraded an Alienware X51 from Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 10 Home. It's running a lot smoother, but the Ethernet connection no longer works. It just says "No Internet" and never connects.

I've tried the following steps, but none have worked so far:

- released and renewed the DHCP lease
- manually set a new IP address
- used the network reset feature
- disabled and re-enabled the Ethernet adapter
- reset the TCP/IP stack
- updated the driver for the Ethernet adapter
- disabled the virtual adapter created by Virtualbox

Are there any other things that I should try? Or is the adapter somehow incompatible with this version of Windows?

For the record, the adapter is a Realtex PCIe GBE Family Controller.

Comment: Try a livecd to confirm its 'just' the OS. I've had an adaptor that didn't work and needed a bios reset to function correctly